# Google Spreadsheets repeating X text Y amount of times in a column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Google Spreadsheets, and I have information populating the sheet through a Form. The data comes through as a timestamp, text, text separated by commas and number separated by commas (Columns A, B, C and D, respectively). [Here's a link to a simplified example sheet I made to show my problem.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YdYvbxT_izMFcKKKtvmiR8zXocYM0SaZsvmoca86ZQc/edit?usp=sharing)

What I want to do is have the Week in B listed as many times as there are activities. So In B2, it says "Week 2", and in C2 there is "Running, Skiing", and so I would like "Week 2" to be written twice going down. In C3, there is only one activity, so I would only want "Week 2" to be written once this time. In the "I" column I showed what I would like to happen.

What I can do (Column G) is use a combination of Transpose, Split and Rept functions to list B2 (Week 2), F2 amount of times (twice). However, at an arbitrary distance below, I then want to repeat the same the same thing with B3 and F3, and so on and so on. I think I need to use ArrayFormula function, but I don't exactly understand how to in this scenario.

Hope I explained my problem properly, if any more information is needed I'll provide it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erase D column. Rewrite D column.

G2:

```
=REPT(B2&", ", F2)
```

Drag fill down.

This should give your table:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({G2:G5& ", ",C2:D5 & ","},, 500000)), ", ", 0)))
```